# How to parse arguments with space inside bash function

Tags: bash, arguments

In bash I am calling function:

```
myFunction "1 2"
myFunction()
{
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"
}
```

this prints me "1 2" and empty row. How I can parse arguments so it will print on one row 1 and on another 2 ? I can not call `myFunction "1"  "2"`  because arguments are stored in some other variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
myFunction()
{
        echo "$1"
        echo "$2"
}

myFunction 1 2
```

Comment: ah ok lol I am so dumb thx a lot

Comment: You said in your question that you `can not call myFunction "1"  "2"`, yet that is how this answer solved the problem...

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want to split the first argument your function receives on space characters. For that, you could use the split+glob operator after having configured the split part to use space as the delimiter and disabled the glob part:

```
myfunction() {
  local -       # make changes to options local to the function.
                # needs bash 4.4 or newer.
  local IFS=' ' # split on space only
  set -o noglob # disable glob part
  set -- $1     # split+glob invoked on $1 by leaving that $1 unquoted,
                # result stored in $1, $2... using set --
  printf '%s\n' "$1"
  printf '%s\n' "$2"
}
myfunction "1 2"
```

Answer (score 2):

That's the same as splitting any variable on spaces. Use word splitting or `read`:

With word splitting:

```
var="foo bar"
set -f              # disable globbing
IFS=' '             # make sure IFS contains (just) a space
printf "%s\n" $var
```

With `read`, for a standard shell (if you know there's only two pieces to split into):

```
var="foo bar"
IFS=' ' read a b <<EOF
$var
EOF
printf "%s\n" "$a" "$b"
```

The same with a here-string (Bash/ksh/zsh):

```
var="foo bar"
IFS=' ' read a b <<< "$var"
printf "%s\n" "$a" "$b"
```

With `read -a` in Bash, or `read -A` in ksh/zsh, you can split the string to an arbitrary number of pieces and put them in an array:

```
var="foo bar"
IFS=' ' read -a arr <<< "$var"     # Bash
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

In all of the above, you can use `$1` in place of `$var` as usual.

The variants with `read` also assume the string doesn't contain multiple lines.

However, in Bash you can also split a multi-line string to an array using any whitespace as separator:

```
IFS=$' \t\n' read -d '' -a arr <<< "$var"
```

---

Of course if you have the string in a variable outside the function, and run `myFunction $var`, the variable will be split to multiple arguments before the function runs.

Comment: I prefer `set -o noglob` over `set -f` as `set -f` means something different in `zsh` (though is not needed there, and `set -f` would be harmless)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, right you are, as always. I didn't realize zsh had changed the meaning of `set -f`, thanks.

Comment: Note that it's `read -A` in ksh93 and zsh. Not sure why bash maintainers chose to break compatibility with them when they added `-a` years later

Comment: Technically, it's the Bourne shell that changed the meaning of `-f`. `zsh` gets it from csh which added -f before the Bourne shell. `set -f` behaves like in the Bourne shell in zsh when in sh emulation.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, ah, that sounds more sensible, actually.